# How to flip a dynamically added image using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### .html

```
<tbody id="item-determination" class="item-table">

</tbody>
```

### .js

`$('<td><img src="image/' + item['Group 1'].toLowerCase() + '.png"/></td>').appendTo(tr);`

The image gets updated and appended to the table according to the data that comes from the service program. 
On hovering over the image I want it to flip and show some text, like it happens here : https://www.ostraining.com/images/coding/jquery-flip/demo/

But as I am not using the similar structure of html, how can I get the same affect from the JQuery line that I am using?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
$(function () {
        //var $btnAdd = $('#btn-add-item');
      //var $rbFlipType = $('input[name=flipType]');
      var $tblItems = $('#tbl-items');
      var $tbodyItems = $tblItems.children('tbody');

      $(function () {
        //var flipType = $rbFlipType.filter(':checked').val();
        //var random = Math.random() * 9999999999999999;
        var item = `<tr>
            <td>
            <div class="flippable-container">
                <div class="flippable">
                <img src="image/' + item['Group 1'].toLowerCase() + '.png" title=""/>
                <h1>$('<td></td>').text(item['Group 1']).appendTo(tr)</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>`;

        $tbodyItems.append(item);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: They are using `jquery.flip.min.js`.

Comment: @PHPglue I have added the cdn for that file. The cdn for jquery is also there.

Comment: `jQueryElement.flip({trigger:'hover'})` it.

Comment: Requires `<div id="flip-this" class="flip-horizontal"> 
    <div class="front"> 
      <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    </div> 
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Some Text in the Back!</h3>
    </div> 
 </div>` HTML layout.

Comment: @PHPglue the HTML layout you mentioned is similar to the link I mentioned. My case is that my HTML layout differs. My html layout has just the two lines I mentioned for the table.

Comment: You would have to at least have two elements within the Element you flip... one with `class='front'` and one with `class='back'`. Why the table layout?

Comment: @PHPglue The table layout is because the person I am doing this for wants it that way. So is there no other way where we can add something to the  `$('<td><img src="image/' + item['Group 1'].toLowerCase() + '.png"/></td>').appendTo(tr);` line?

Comment: I don't see `tr`. I'm assuming it's a table row within the `tbody`. Is that correct? Supply more code and I have an easy solution.

Comment: @PHPglue Yes tr is a table row. It automatically appends the data to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the flipping animation through CSS but you really have to restructure the HTML I guess.

```js
$(function () {
  var $btnAdd = $('#btn-add-item');
  var $rbFlipType = $('input[name=flipType]');
  var $tblItems = $('#tbl-items');
  var $tbodyItems = $tblItems.children('tbody');
  
  $btnAdd.click(function () {
    var flipType = $rbFlipType.filter(':checked').val();
    var random = Math.random() * 9999999999999999;
    /* Template literal
    var item = `<tr>
     <td>
       <div class="flippable-container">
         <div class="flippable ${flipType}">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats?randomQueryString=${random}" title="">
            <h1>${flipType}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>`;
    */
    var item = '<tr>' +
      '<td>' +
        '<div class="flippable-container">' +
          '<div class="flippable ' + flipType + '">' +
            '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats?randomQueryString=' + random + '" title="">' +
            '<h1>' + flipType + '</h1>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
    
    $tbodyItems.append(item);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  font: normal 14px/1.8 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.flippable-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flippable {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  width: 400px;
}

.flippable img,
.flippable h1 {
  backface-visibility: hidden; /* Don't show the backside of the element when rotated. */
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
}

.flippable img {
  z-index: 1; /* Keep the img in front. */
}

.flippable h1 {
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flippable.vertical img {
  transform: rotateX(0);
}

.flippable.vertical h1,
.flippable.vertical:hover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flippable.horizontal img {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}

.flippable.horizontal h1,
.flippable.horizontal:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <label for="rb-flip-type-horizontal">
    <input id="rb-flip-type-horizontal" type="radio" value="horizontal" name="flipType">
    Horizontal
  </label>
  <label for="rb-flip-type-vertical">
    <input id="rb-flip-type-vertical" type="radio" value="vertical" name="flipType">
    Vertical
  </label>
  <button id="btn-add-item">
    Add
  </button>
  <table id="tbl-items">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Based off of [David Walsh's flip](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip).

Comment: This looks great! But can we get rid of the buttons? The image appears by itself without any need to press any buttons. Also if horizontal or vertical is the requirement here, I just need it to work horizontally.

Comment: @SteveDoson, I just added those buttons to add the images. It's up to you how you want to use it :)

Comment: I added the modified version of your javascript part in my code above. But I am getting an error saying that the image cannot be found. Please have a look. I also added just `id="tbl-items"` in the table tag, like you showed and the entire css is the same.

Comment: @SteveDoson if you're not familiar with JS template literals, change `var item = ...` to the old string concatenation by using `+` (`'<tr> + <td> + <div class="flippable-container"> + <div class="flippable"> + <img src="image/' + item['Group 1'].toLowerCase() + '">'`). Also, change the variable name from `item` to another one since you're using `item['Group 1'].toLowerCase()`

Comment: @SteveDoson updated to use `+` string concatenation.

Comment: I am actually a little new to this stuff. Learning more by building. If you see the code I gave above I am removing the bttnAdd.click. The image is now not appearing at all the console is showing errors like cannot read property .toLowerCase() of jquery.min.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154952/discussion-between-dork-and-steve-doson).